# Internal path mapping in windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, 64-bit

I have a windows7 machine in which i am creating a file through java code in following path

**C:\Users\123\Application Data\XYZ**

but physically it is getting created here

**C:\Users\123\AppData\Roaming\XYZ**

please tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because one is a legacy path, and the other is the current preferred folder path. Both lead to the same location.

See e.g. [Application Compatibility: Junction Points and Backup Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756982.aspx):

> In Windows Vista® and Windows Server® 2008, the default location of user data has changed. An example of this change is the Documents and Settings directory, which has been moved from %systemdrive%\Documents and Settings to %systemdrive%\Users.

and:

> ..\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\ [is mapped to] ..\Users\\AppData\Roaming